# On which host does this parallel command hang?

Tags: gnu-parallel

I run this parallel command:

```
parallel -q -j0 ssh {} 'echo {}; tmp/myscript' ::: host1 host2 host3 ....
```

Above line shows a result for most hosts.

Unfortunately the parallel command hangs on some host. The script seems to be in an endless loop.

How can I detect on which host it hangs?

All hosts are reachable. I tested this with this command:

```
parallel -q -j0 ssh {} 'echo {}; date' ::: host1 host2 host3 ....
```

Comment: The problem is that "endless loop" doesn't mean failed job and it doesn't emit any error sratus

Answer (score 3):

I would use `--timeout 1000%`: If one job takes 10 times longer that the typical runtime, kill it.

Then I would use `--joblog mylog` to see which job timed out (exit val = -1).

You could also use `--nonall` (instead of `-q ssh`) and `--tag` to see which jobs completed (and thus deducing which one is stuck).

Comment: I use `parallel` since several month, but `--timeout 1000%` was new to me. Thank you!

Comment: I am unsure if `--nonall` does help me. In my current use case I want to run the job only once on every given host. I don't want it to run twice on a host. But maybe I did not understood the man page.

Comment: `--nonall` runs a single command on a list of hosts, which are given by `-S` or `--slf`.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell with the `ps` command.

Run your script again, wait until it hangs, then run:

`ps -elf | grep ssh`

You should see the `ssh` process for the node that this has "hung" on.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution without parallel.

I run it se

```
for host in host1 host2 ...; do echo $host; ssh $host tmp/myscript; echo; done
```

This way I see where it hangs.